# Getting not configured error while sending email in php-codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Please see my email sending code below and it is showing the following error while sending the email..

> Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

My Controller:

```
 $from_email= "******"; 
 $to_email = 'dummy@dummy.com';
 $subject='Password Reset Request';
 $htmlContent = '<p>'.$link.'</p>';
     $this->load->library('email'); 
     $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
     $this->email->initialize($config);
     $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 
     $this->email->from($from_email,'*****'); 
     $this->email->to($to_email);
     $this->email->subject($subject); 
     $this->email->message($htmlContent);           
     $this->email->send();
```

This condition is showing the above error. Actually, it was working fine initially in development stage, but now it is not..What could have gone wrong in this query...Thank you in advance..

Comment: have you configure `php.ini` file?

Comment: Where are your configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

you're using `$this->email->initialize($config);` but there is no actual configs on your code. And as per your error **Unable to send email using PHP mail()**, your server can run through **sendmail**.

[Email Class in codeingiter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences)

---

[Example](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences)

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

---

To check outgoing mail with this on server

```
 telnet google.com 25 # 587 or  2095 ,2096
```

Most server outgoing ports will be 25 or 587

Comment: Exit status code: 1
    Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
    Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be 
   configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: @julie use smtp and try then

Answer (score 0):

if you are in localhost the code work, are you in live server ?
if your URL is **siteurl.domain** then try ,

```
    $from_email= "email@siteurl.domain";  //from email must be from same server url
    $to_email = 'dummy@dummy.com';
    $subject='Password Reset Request';
    $htmlContent = '<p>'.$link.'</p>';

    //{INCLUDE SMTP CONFIG HERE IF THIS NOT WORKiNG THIS METHOD}

    $config['mailtype']  = 'html';
    $config['charset']   = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap']  = TRUE;
    $config['newline']   = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
    $this->email->initialize($config);     
    $this->email->from('$from_email', 'sender name');   
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($htmlContent);
    $this->email->send();
```

else  try with SMTP:),

```
     //SMTP CONFIG

     $config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
     $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //smtp host name
     $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
     $config['smtp_user'] = 'ji******@gmail.com';
     $config['smtp_pass'] = '*******'; //$from_email password
     //Continue above code
```

I'm not able to comment(sorry) :), 
sometimes SMTP method not working with Bluehost account :(

Comment: sender email domain must be from the same server: eg if your site is **server.domain**  then sender email  **username@server.domain**, else try SMTP